# Delete duplicate records in MySQL including the original

Tags: mysql, duplicates

My question is this,

I have a table with an email, firstname, and lastname columns. What query could I use to delete the duplicates, *including* the original?

So if the table has two records like so:

```
johndoe@email.com | john | doe    
johndoe@email.com | john | doe
```

How could I delete both records, so that the record is completely removed from the table?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will delete all rows that have the same email, firstname and lastname:

```
DELETE yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN (SELECT email, firstname, lastname
                        FROM yourtable
                        GROUP BY email, firstname, lastname
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1) dup
  ON yourtable.email = dup.email
     AND yourtable.firstname = dup.firstname
     AND yourtable.lastname = dup.lastname
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd2b2/1).

I'm using a subquery that will return all duplicates, and I'm joining all duplicates with yourtable itself, and I'm deleting all rows that match the join.

Edit: if you have all duplicates in a table called duplicates, you could use this delete query:

```
DELETE Contacts.*
FROM
  Contacts INNER JOIN Duplicates
  ON Contacts.email = Duplicates.email
     AND Contacts.firstname = Duplicates.firstname
     AND Contacts.lastname = Duplicates.lastname
```

this will delete all rows from contacts that match the rows on duplicates (with the same email, same firstname and same lastname)

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me so quickly. The fiddle works brilliantly, however when I run the query (attempted twice) it hangs with a blinking cursor. Any ideas?


There are around 50,000 records and I'm running on a Core i7 with 12 GB of RAM

Comment: how big is your table? you could try to add an index on (email, firstname, lastname)

Comment: (Edited my last comment) There are about 50,000 records. I'm running with Core i7-3770 with 12GB of RAM.


How about this.. I have 1 table, called "Duplicates" (identical fields) and another table, "Contacts" (identical fields). Would it be possible to setup a query to remove all records in "Contacts" that have the same record in "Duplicates"?

Comment: @marshmallow i updated my answer, and added a query that will remove all contacts that are present also in the duplicates table

Comment: Thanks again for your help, both methods worked well. Both queries took around 15 minutes to complete, which only gave the appearance of locking up. You're a life-saver.